# Is Defrag "invisible" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, defragment

After (buzzard's luck) installing Visual Studio 2013 RC a couple of days ago, and then Visual Studio 2013 RTM yesterday, I thought I should defrag, what with all that install/uninstall activity going on.

So I mashed the Window key and typed Defrag, and up came the "Defrag" search result. I mashed the Enter key and ... nothing ... Is Defrag working behind the scenes? I see no icon on the task bar ... Is there a trick to defragging beyond what I did?

Comment: Windows has continously defragged your system since Windows 7.  In any event the default tool does a horrible job, I suggest using, http://www.piriform.com/defraggler instead.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug, it's a feeeeeeatureeeee.

Optimize Drives replaced Disk Defragmenter. Meet the new app, same as the old app.

Also accessible via My Computer, pick your hard drive, clicking on the Manage tab and then select the Optimize button.

Now me, I like MyDefrag which uses the underlying code of Windows Defrag services but has a better UI with more capabilities. It's also stable, reliable, has a decent scheduler and is crapware-free. http://www.mydefrag.com/ And, I get no reward or compensation from that recommendation.